# Django REST Framework: Custom Validator for Image URL Not Working as Expected

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a Django REST Framework project where I have a ProjectModel with both an image_file field (for uploaded images) and an image_url field (for externally hosted images). Additionally, I have a custom validator (ImageURLValidator) to validate the image_url field. The models and serializer classes look like this:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class ProjectModel(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to='project/%Y/%m/%d'
    )

    image_url = models.URLField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .validators import ImageURLValidator
from .models import ProjectModel

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.URLField(
        required=False,
        allow_null=True,
        allow_blank=True,
        validators=[ImageURLValidator()]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectModel
        fields = ['id', 'image_file', 'image_url']
```

validators.py

```
import requests
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ImageURLValidator:

    def __call__(self, value):
        if not value.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("URL must start with 'http://' or 'https://'")
            )

        try:
            validators.URLValidator()(value)
        except serializers.ValidationError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("Invalid URL format")
            )

        # Fetch content from URL and check image format
        response = None
        try:
            response = requests.get(value)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Check for error status
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("Error fetching content from URL: %(error)s") % {'error': str(e)}
            )

        content_type = response.headers['content-type']
        if not content_type.startswith(('image/')):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("URL must point to an image")
            )
```

The custom validator ImageURLValidator is intended to validate that the image_url field starts with either 'http://' or 'https://'. Despite implementing the validator and running unit tests, the validation error message received does not match the expected error message. The issue persists, and the error message looks like this:

```
{'image_url': [ErrorDetail(string="URL must start with 'http://' or 'https://'", code='invalid')]}
```

expected:

```
{'image_url': ["URL must start with 'http://' or 'https://'"]}
```

unittest:

```
class TestFail(TestBase):

    def test_file_url_starts_with_http_or_https(self):
        # remove http:// or https://
        image_url = self.faker.image_url(width=640, height=480)
        pattern = re.compile(r'https?://')
        image_url = pattern.sub('', image_url)

        post_data = {
            'image_url': image_url,
        }

        url_name = "create-project"
        url = f"{APP_LABEL}:{url_name}"
        end_point = reverse(url)
        response = self.client.post(
            end_point,
            post_data,
            # format="multipart"
        )

        expected = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        actual = response.status_code
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

        

        msg = _("URL must start with 'http://' or 'https://'")
        expected = {'image_url': [msg]}
        actual = response.data
        self.assertDictEqual(expected, actual)
```

Comment: The `ExpectedResult` is simply wrong, how would `["URL must start with 'http://' or 'https://'", code='invalid']` even make sense? you can not use `code=...` in a list (literal).

Comment: sorry, that part slipped my mind; I fixed it